# Customize email body (docusign API)

Tags: docusignapi

I am using esign 4.1.0 and I am trying to customize the email body by API doing this:

```
EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envelopeDefinition.setEmailBlurb("Customized text");
```

But when i receive the email, i notice that docusign has added the first two lines above "Customized text". Is there any possibility to remove those lines? I don't need them.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to use the resource file which includes many elements of text and images that show in different places in the product.

https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide&topicId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide.pdf&_LANG=enus has full documentation of this process and how you modify the resource file.